# Why my Delphi's Android Emulator does not run the applications?

Tags: android, delphi, android-emulator, delphi-xe5

I installed `Delphi XE5`, I runned Delphi's `Android Tools` and updated all the packages suggested by it. Only then the `Emulator` worked.

Now I created some android apps as tests to run. In my phone they work, but when I press the `run` button, Delphi asks if I want to load and use the `Android Emulator`.

It starts Ok, then I unblock it by swapping the mouse, and after some seconds the app starts **but I see only a totally black screen**.

If I click `home` button on the emulator and then `run` again in Delphi, the black screen appears again, meaning that the app was load but it's main window do not load.

What my I be doing wrong?

Comment: The Android Tools are not Embarcadero's, they are Google's. Delphi simply installs Google's SDK.  However, Google's Android emulator basically SUCKS, you are better off just debugging on a real device.

Comment: Have a look if something from the answers here help you: http://stackoverflow.com/q/1554099/1970843

Comment: FMX uses a GPU, So you must enable the GPU flag for your emulator, and your PC must have a non discrete GPU.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have installed Eclipse and the android SDK tools for it you should change the default Delphi SDK settings.

Do this as follows:

1. In delphi open tab tools
2. options
3. SDK manager
4. Set de SDK properties to the eclipse locations on your computer

if you have done this correctly you should be able to make a new emulator in eclipse and see it in delphi.

When you create a new emulator you need to set the CPU to ARM and also check Use host GPU otherwise it can't run the delphi apps!

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the emulator from within a virtual machine - e.g. Within parallels on a mac?.  If so, you can pretty well forget being able to use the emulator.

The emulators are extremely resource hungry and are probably best run on a well-spec'd dedicated machine.

Comment: I use it in my machine with Delphi. It's Delphi that runs it. I have another Android SDK and Emu that runs for Eclipse. I have a W7 64bit in a Intel Core i7 with 8GB.